# iOS 11 deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable always return NO and Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=11. How to make deferredlocationupdates work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ios11

I am trying to use allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled:timeout:) to defer the location updates. The documentation followed is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates.
Even though by trying various ways to detach the phone from debugger, keeping phone idle for longer duration the Deferring is not working. Please advice if someone has tried this on iOS 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatly, despite of all documentation and after weeks of frustrating development effort, I excepted the fact, that this functionality is not supported anymore. I tested it in all possible situations on 7 different real devices (iPads and iPhones, 5s up to 7) ... no success.

It did work perfectly on IOS 9, this is why I trust, that I know how to do it. But I tried every hint I found here and elsewere... no success under IOS 10 and 11.

If you look around you will find numerous angry comments from other coder. It‘s a shame, but we have to except the facts.